# Data transfer from 12.04 to 14.04 using same hostname?

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, lvm

I've been using my 12.04 server for a year and a half. I'd like to install 14.04 on a new drive and transfer all my data over once that is complete.  I have 720GB of files to to deal with.

12.04 was setup using LVM.

I'd like to use the same hostname.

I'd prefer a clean install as opposed to an upgrade.

What would be the best way go about this? Is it as simple as booting to the new install and mounting the 12.04 VG? I suppose I'd have to manually set up LVM on 14.04 if I want to use the same hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you organised your old system.

If you have a single / filesystem with data and programs mixed in you could:
 - Install the new system on a new logical volume
 - Mount your old system on /mnt/old or something similar
 - Create a bunch of symlinks from /var/data to /mnt/old/var/data, /home/someone to /mnt/old/home/someone, etc
It is not terribly elegant but you will save yourself copying stuff around.

If you had your /home and/or /var/data on separate logical volumes then you can just remount them on their new places.

Comment: @smurf That was simpler than I'd envisioned.  Thanks.